# comparing elements of a list of list and removing

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l=[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7]]
```

so I have a list like this and I want to traverse through this list to check if the zeroth index of each sublist is equivalent to one another so check if any zeroth index of each sublist is equal to another, and then if two of or more are similar check the second index in the sublist and only keep the sublist with lowest int value and remove all others.

so the output should be that

```
[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
```

so it removes the sublist with the higher int in the second index

I'm thinking something like this

```
for i in l:
    for k in i:
        if k[0]=i[0][0]:
            # then I dont know
```

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be ordered by the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more option may be this:

```
l = [['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7]]

# initialize a dict
d = {x[0]: list() for x in l}

# lambda function to compare values
f = lambda x: x if not d[x[0]] or x[2] < d[x[0]][2] else d[x[0]]

# list comprehension to iterate and process the list of values
[d.update({x[0]: f(x)}) for x in l]

# output exected: [['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
print(list(d.values()))
```

Comment: this works, but only for comparing tow sublists how do I change it so it compares n sublists?

Comment: Be a bit more specific, give an example.

Comment: `l = [['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7],['b', 'random_str4', 6],['b', 'random_str5', 8]]` .So in an example like that lets say I have n amount of sublists with string 'b' that is identical and the issue is that it will still only compare the first two that the loop finds. The idea is that in this example it should be able to look at all four of the above sublists and only keep the sublist with the lowest int value compared to the others. so the output would be `[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]` I.e removes the other sublists

Comment: I checked it just now and it works properly, have you wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with `pandas`, a `sort_values` and a `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
l=[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7]]

#create dataframe from list of list
df = pd.DataFrame(l)

#sort column based on third column / index = 2
df = df.sort_values(by=2)

#groupby first column and only take first entry which is lowest int after sort.
df = df.groupby(0).head(1)

#put back to list of list
df = df.values.tolist()

print(df)
```

prints out

```
[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
```

Comment: Huge overkill if OP does not already use pandas in this project

Answer (score 0):

This list-comprehension is fairly horrible, but does what you're after - find the minimum element based on third element, for every sublist with first element iterating over a set of first elements.

```
>>> [min((x for x in l if x[0] == y), key=lambda x: x[2]) for y in set(z[0] for z in l)]
[['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['a', 'random_str', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by first element, and in each group find min by third:

```
f2 = lambda x: x[2]
f0 = lambda x: x[0]
[min(subl, key=f2) for _, subl in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=f0), key=f0)]
# => [['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
```

Comment: I think you need to sort before `groupby` usage.

Answer (score 0):

not so good/pythonic way, but you can use `dictionary` to get result

```
l=[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7]]
res = {}
for sublist in l:
    if sublist[0] not in res.keys():
        res.update({sublist[0]:[sublist[1], sublist[2]]})
    else:
        if sublist[2]<res[sublist[0]][1]:
            res[sublist[0]][1] = sublist[2]

final_res = [[index, res[index][0], res[index][1]] for index, value in res.items()]
print(final_res)
```

output

```
[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
```

Comment: this works, but only for comparing tow sublists how do I change it so it compares n sublists?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. (I'm sure you could reduce the time complexity with a clever algorithm that does not sort, but unless we're talking about a bottleneck here you should not be too concerned about that.)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby                                                          
>>> from operator import itemgetter                                                        
>>>                                                                                        
>>> first, third = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(2)                                           
>>> l = [['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7]] 
>>>        
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(l), key=first)                                                 
>>> [min(list(group), key=third) for _, group in groups]                                  
[['a', 'random_str', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
```

The idea is to group your data by the first element in each sublist. `groupby` needs `l` to be sorted in order to do that. (`sorted` already sorts lexicographically, but you could optimize it by using `sorted(l, key=first)` such that only the first element is considered for sorting.) Afterwards, we extract the minimum of each group with respect to element three (index 2).

All of this could be done in one line, but I find `groupby` oneliners terribly unreadable, so I opted for a solution with more lines and some self-documenting variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this via dataframe is the easiest and most efficient according to me. Try

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['a', 'random_str4', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5], ['b', 'random_str3', 7], ['a', 'random_str2', 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(by = 2)
df = df.drop_duplicates(0)
df.values.tolist()
```

This outputs the desired result, i.e.,

```
[['a', 'random_str4', 4], ['b', 'random_str2', 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the most feasible solution, but works fine for the mean time.
Assuming the list is sorted in Ascending order,

```
def get_result(l) :
    temp_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(l) - 1 :
        min = l[i]
        while i<len(l)-1 and l[i][0] == l[i+1][0] :
            if l[i][2] < l[i+1][2] :
                min = l[i]
            else :
                min = l[i+1]
            i += 1
        temp_list.append(min)
        i += 1
    return temp_list
```

do,

```
print(get_result(l))
```

if the list is sorted, use this before invoking the method,

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```